# Another way to concurrently RDP windows 7 after patch?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote

I've patched my windows 7 so to allow concurrent rdp connections and I would like to keep one user using it keyboard/mouse and another one remote. Is it only possible with windows builtin rdp program (which need windows ultimate) or is it also possible with something like VNC? I believe the program would have to loggin as another user (ie not the user using keyboard/mouse).

Answer (score 0):

```
user1 = console user
user2 = remote user
```

One option is to add user2 to local group named `Remote Desktop Users` or give him Administrator rights.

Another option is to select users from `My computer > options > remote`.